# Innertext vba optimization

Tags: excel, vba

I have been using the following vba to extract data and it is fine on most days. However, I just encountered an error today. Can anyone please help to point me in the correct direction to improve the vba? thanks

```
Sub ExtractCP()
Dim ie As Object
Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A2:AZ3000").Clear


Set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")

With ie
    .Visible = False
    .Navigate "http://www.yahoo.com/"
    Do Until .ReadyState = 4: DoEvents: Loop



        x = .Document.body.innertext




        x = Split(x, Chr(13))
        Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("00:00:03"))



        Sheet2.Cells(1, 1).Resize(UBound(x)) = Application.Transpose(x)

        .Quit
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: What is the error and on which line is it thrown?

Comment: run-time error 1004 application-defined or object-defined error. Thrown on sheet2.cells(1,1).Resize(Ubound(x)) = Application.Transpose(x)

Comment: try `Ubound(x)+1`

Comment: Hi Scott. Thanks for the prompt response. Tried but no luck with it. Any other idea?

Comment: It works for me so I am at a loss.  check that `x` is not nothing.

Comment: ubound(x) = 41 in debug mode.

Comment: One last test put it horizantal and see if it is the Transpose part: `Sheet2.Cells(1, 1).Resize(,UBound(x)).VAlue = x`.  Transpose does have a limit and some of the cells may be hitting that.

Comment: Hi Scott. Its still the same. However, the error message is not shown if I put ubound(x)-30 but the whole content from the web is not captured.